# How to append the keyword "Continued" word with table header in SSRS on all the subsequent pages?

Tags: sql-server, data-visualization, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have created RDL using SSRS that has one tablix with 4 fields and I have set the dataset for the tablix. The problem here is when the dataset rows increases then the tablix extends to new pages. Let say for example the table header name is "Employees". When the table extends to new pages because of more rows in the datasets, then we have to repeat the table header in all the new pages when its starts like "Employees continued". By properties we can repeat the table header "Employees" but how to achieve "Employees continued" in all subsequent pages.

Thanks,
Vidhselva

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted?

Answer (score 1):

In your page header, set the text box to an expression something like this.

```
="Employees " & IIF(Globals!PageNumber>1, " continued", "")
```

Comment: #Alan Schofield For example, I said only one table in my rdl. If only one tablix means, I can use your fix but I have many tablix in my rdl, the same requirement needed for all those. So fix in page header is not possible I think.

Comment: You said you had 1 tablix, hence the answer for 1 tablix. I'll edit my answer with another possible (untested) solution.

Comment: Okay Thanks @alan-schofield

Comment: Actually I'm not sure this is possible thinking about it. I did a little research and found this which may help. 

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrishays/2006/09/27/continued-header-on-subsequent-pages/

Also, in future, please be clear when you ask a question. You question was misleading.